# Pass defined language to mapbox navigation class with React Native & Swift

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-ios

Im trying to create a Mapbox navigation component with React Native. So my question is whats the best way to implement it via the React Native Component? All help is appreciated. Thanks

**RN Component**

```
var navDemo = NativeModules.NavDemo;
 navDemo.renderNaviDemo(
          (originLat = this.props.currentLocation.coords.latitude),
          (originLon = this.props.currentLocation.coords.longitude),
          (originName = "Start"),
          (destinationLat = this.state.manoeuvreDetails.geometry
            .coordinates[1]),
          (destinationLon = this.state.manoeuvreDetails.geometry
            .coordinates[0]),
          (destinationName = this.state.manoeuvreDetails.name)
        );
```

**Swift Class**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapboxCoreNavigation
import MapboxNavigation
import MapboxDirections
import Mapbox

@objc(NavDemo)
class NavDemo: NSObject {

  @objc
  func renderNaviDemo(_ originLat: NSNumber, oriLon originLon: NSNumber, oriName originName: NSString, destLat destinationLat: NSNumber, destLon destinationLon: NSNumber, destName destinationName: NSString) {

    let origin = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(truncating: originLat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(truncating: originLon)), name: originName as String)
    let destination = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(truncating: destinationLat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(truncating: destinationLon)), name: destinationName as String)

    let options = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [origin, destination])

    Directions.shared.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
      guard let route = routes?.first else { return }

      let navigationService = MapboxNavigationService(route: route, simulating: .never)
      let navigationOptions = NavigationOptions(navigationService: navigationService)

      let viewController = NavigationViewController(for: route, options: navigationOptions)
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
      appDelegate!.window!!.rootViewController!.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```